# Will you please tell me how to get test coverage for finish method were sending error mails in this batch class

Tags: code-coverage

```
public class MyBatchable implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
    
Exception[] errors = new Exception[0];
    public Iterable<SObject> start(...) {
        ...
    }
    
public void execute(...) {
        
try {
            ...
        } 
catch(Exception e) {
            
errors.add(e);
        }
    }
    
public void finish(...) {
        
if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
 
          
 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            mail.setSubject('Errors occurred during batch process.');

            mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());

            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

            mail.setPlainTextBody(buildBodyFor(errors));

            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] { mail });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to share your test code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess would be to create a batch object, add errors into your array and then manually call the finish element.
As Errors is public and so is the finish method, just call them :

```
MyBatchable b = new MyBatchable();
b.errors.add(new AurahandledException('a dummy Error'));
b.finish(null);
```

Comment: @prasanthroyal and one would want to do asserts to prove that finish() sends an email if errors is non-Null